# SharePoint Services are getting stopped and disabled automatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, services

I'm my SharePoint 2016 on premises farm,  I've 2 app server and 3 WFE Servers, In that I'm facing an issue with one particular app server and one WFE server, the issue is all the Services running with Farm account as identity. they are getting stopped and switching to Disabled Start type , even after i change it to automatic and make the running. In a few hours the status is changing automatically.

I tired using a different Farm account identity, but the issue remains the same with that account as well.
I also tried,  rebooting the server, did IISRESET and Installed the latest CU updates then ran the PS config wizard, but nothing helps as of now.

[image]

can anyone please help with an idea to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Please try the following troubleshooting:**

- 1.Account password expired

Please updated password under managed service account of SP central admin.

- 2.View detailed errors through Windows Logs

[image]

———————————————— **Updated Answer** ——————————————

**Please try the following troubleshooting:**

- Please make sure that all machines of SharePoint Server have the same CU

1)Sign in the **SharePoint Central Administration** as a global admin

2)Click on "**Upgrade and Migration**"on the Left Navigation bar >> click on "**Check product and patch installation status**" >> check all machines of SharePoint Server have the same CU

[image]

- View diagnostic logs through **ULS logs**.

More information, please refer to this articel [Configure diagnostic logging in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/configure-diagnostic-logging?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Hi,  thanks for answering, i don't think the issue is with the Service Account because the same account has been used in other server's services they are all working fine and I don't find any clue in the event viewers

Comment: Hi, Jegan Baskaran. I have updated my answer, hope this helps you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi EchoDu_MSFT thank you so much for your answer , i have checked the CU Updates in all the server,  they are all same  and up to date, I'm the one who installs them every month in my sharepoint farm so I'll install the upcoming CU updates for Jan month and update the results, if you have any other troubleshooting step , pls let me know

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the service account password was not changed recently - if changed, update the password in service configuration as well.

If that is not the case, you may try the below:

- Index Reset and Full Crawl

You may refer to the below thread for a similar issue:

[SharePoint Search Administration exceptions in Event Log](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-us/8141a5a5-b4c9-44e5-926b-acfc6b30e897/sharepoint-search-administration-exceptions-in-event-log)